# Is this a known measure of "effective degrees of freedom" in regression?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, references, degrees-of-freedom

Suppose $x,y$ are I.I.D random variables in $d$ dimensions. Consider the following quantity:

$$R=\frac{(E\|x\|^2)^2}{E\langle x, y\rangle^2}$$

equivalently for empirical distribution with data matrix $X$

$$R=\frac{(\operatorname{Tr}X'X)^2}{\operatorname{Tr}X'XX'X}$$

Does this quantity come up in statistics literature?

This came up recently under ML as "effective rank $R_0$" ([Bartlett](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.11300) Lemma 5). It's similar to quantity mentioned in wikipedia [under](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)#Regression_effective_degrees_of_freedom) Satterthwaite approximation, except where the hat matrix $H=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is replaced with $X$.

Comment: What do you mean by "degrees of freedom" here? It is usually meant as a property of a statistical model, not the data.

Comment: Good question, trying to nail down the terminology, but one example is chi-squared distribution -- it has a degrees of freedom parameter, hence, we can talk about corresponding dataset having a "degrees of freedom" statistic

Comment: OK, so how do you define "degrees of freedom" here?

Comment: This talks about degrees of freedom as a property of the data https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)#Regression_effective_degrees_of_freedom

Comment: No, it doesn't, it still discusses statistical models, as the whole article which starts with a definition "In statistics, the number of degrees of freedom is the number of values in the final calculation of a statistic that are free to vary."

Comment: In that link under "Satterthwaite approximation" it provides the following degrees of freedom statistic $$\frac{\operatorname{Tr}(H'H)^2}{\operatorname{Tr}(H'HH'H)}$$ it is similar to the $R$ statistic in the question in that it is computed for a particular dataset

Comment: The one described under "regression effective degrees of freedom, appropriate definitions can include the trace of the hat matrix"? So you mean calculating degrees of freedom for a linear regression model?

Comment: Thanks for clarification, yes, I'm looking for variations of what the article calls "regression effective degrees of freedom" statistics

Comment: BTW, this earlier [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/how-to-understand-degrees-of-freedom) characterizes degrees of freedom as the number of independent degrees of information that go into an estimate. In that sense, degrees of freedom is a property of 1) data 2) model 3) estimating procedure. A dataset which is all zeros would have 0 independent pieces of information

Answer (score 1):

This quantity seems to reduce to "Welch-Satterthwaite degrees of freedom" is the limit of variance of $x,y$ going to 0